# using rbindlists for nested lists in R

Tags: r, list, data.table, rbind

I have a nested list as showed below. This is an simplified example, my original data has many hundres of items.

```
mtcars
mtcars <- mtcars[1:15,]
mtcars <- as.data.table(mtcars)

iris
iris <- iris[1:10,]
iris <- as.data.table(iris)

result <- vector("list", 3)
names <- c("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3")
names(result) <- names

testList1 <- list(mtcars, iris)

rm(result)
result <- list(Item1 = list(cars = mtcars,
                            flowers = iris),
               Item2 = list(cars = mtcars,
                            flowers = iris),
               Item3 = list(cars = mtcars,
                            flowers = iris))
```

which i want to summarise results, such that I become two data.tables : one for `flowers` and the other one fro `cars`.

I tried using `result <- rbindlist(result, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)` but that results in an error.

The desired outcome is:

```
testList1 <- list(iris, iris, iris)
flowers <- rbindlist(testList1, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
flowers

testList1 <- list(mtcars, mtcars, mtcars)
cars <- rbindlist(testList1, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
cars
```

How can i bind the nested list, considering that the original `results` is much larger than the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `purrr`'s `transpose` and `bind_rows` from `dplyr`.

```
library(purrr)
transpose(result) %>% map(dplyr::bind_rows)

#$cars
#     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 3: 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# 4: 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# 5: 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#...

#$flowers
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#...
```

---

We can add an `'id'` column :

```
transpose(result) %>% map(dplyr::bind_rows, .id = "id")

#$cars
#     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb    id
# 1: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 Item1
# 2: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 Item1
# 3: 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 Item1
#...
#...
#43: 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3 Item3
#44: 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3 Item3
#45: 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4 Item3
#     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb    id

#$flowers
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species    id
# 1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa Item1
# 2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa Item1
# 3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa Item1
#...
#29:          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa Item3
#30:          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa Item3
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species    id
```

Comment: is it possible to add an indicator to which item each of the rows belongs? Item1, Item2 or Item3?

Comment: the transpose function fails on my real data. i just noticed in my read data, that one of my Items, say Item2 does not have a flowers table, which a believe is the reason for failing. How can i overecome this?

Comment: You can use `bind_rows` with `.id`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rbindlist` if we loop over the `names` of the inner list

```
library(data.table)
lapply(setNames(names(result[[1]]), names(result[[1]])), 
        function(nm)  rbindlist(lapply(result, `[[`, nm)))
#$cars
#     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 3: 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# 4: 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# 5: 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# 6: 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
# 7: 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
# 8: 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
# 9: 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
# ...


#$flowers
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6:          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
# 7:          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
# 8:          5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
# ..
```

---

If we need the 'id', then specify the `idcol` option in `rbindlist`

```
lapply(setNames(names(result[[1]]), names(result[[1]])),
    function(nm)  rbindlist(lapply(result, `[[`, nm), idcol = 'id'))
```